# Повторное использование фрагментов

Tags: android, android-fragment

У меня есть одна активити и на нее я подгружаю разные фрагменты. Как можно организовать их адекватное повторное использование, чтобы не получилось наслаивания в стеке одинаковых фрагментов? Есть вариант использовать методы show(), hide(), но все равно нужно вытаскивать из глубины стека фрагменты

UPD

Я наследую фрагменты от главного класса, в котором реализовал следующие методы:

```
void add(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    if (!isFragmentExist(tag)) {
        mTransaction = mManager.beginTransaction();
        mTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        mTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag);
        mTransaction.commit();
    } else {
        popBackStack(tag);
    }

  void popBackStack (String tag) {
    mManager.popBackStack(tag, getSupportFragmentManager().POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
}


    void remove(String tag) {
    if (isFragmentExist(tag)) {
        mTransaction = mManager.beginTransaction();
        mTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
        mTransaction.remove(getFragmentByTag(tag));
        mTransaction.commit();
    }
}

    boolean isFragmentExist(String tag) {
    return (getFragmentByTag(tag) != null)? true: false;
}

Fragment getFragmentByTag(String tag) {
    return mManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы почти на верном пути. Давайте фрагментам уникальные тэги, спрашивайте FragmentManager если уже что-то есть под нужным тэгом. Если есть -- переиспользуйте, если нет -- создайте новый. Как-то так.